# imageview autolink

Tags: android

I am new to android. From xml I retrieved image which is inscribed in hyperlink ()
When there is click event on image I want page to redirect to that hyperlink. How to do so? (Similar to autolink of textview) how to implement it ?

Answer (score 2):

//in your activity get the imageview

```
ImageView imgLink=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.weblink);
        imgLink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent link=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                startActivity(link);    
            }
        });
```