# How to add URL to an image in android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want in my app that when someone clicks the image it opens with the default browser.

I have searched everywhere but no method helps me.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".Home_Activity"
android:background="#FF0000">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/AppTitleimage1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/fra"
    android:contentDescription="@string/AppTitleImageS"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

How can I add a link to an image that opens in a default browser

Thanks

So I found this:

```
ImageView imgLink=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.weblink);
    imgLink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent link=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
            startActivity(link);    
        }
    });
```

But when I paste it in my java class it says:

"Cannot resolve method 'findViewById'(?)
and
"cannot resolve symbol 'weblink'
and
"cannot resolve method startActivity(android.content.intent)

My question is different and that answer is not working

Comment: duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356655/imageview-autolink

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fastest way to set this up is likely add

```
android:onClick="goToUrl"
```

to your imageview and add this function to your class.

```
 private void goToUrl (View view) {
        String url = "http://www.google.com"
        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
        startActivity(launchBrowser);
 }
```

Comment: Hi ashley,  
where i have to paste this?

Comment: The top part is supposed to go into your image xml view.  The other part you enter into the class that you are going to be using the onclick effect.  Probably an activity class or fragment.

Answer (score 4):

you can implement `onClick` for `imageView` and can open url from there:

example:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.AppTitleimage1);
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
        public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"); 
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent); 
            }
         });
```

Comment: where i have to paste this?

Comment: In onCreate of your activity after you set content .

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView imgLink=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.AppTitleimage1);
imgLink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String url = "http://www.example.com";
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);   
    }
});
```